# Expression for "impression of a dead insect on a paper"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

Is there a term to describe the impression of a insect that is formed if the same is crushed between the pages of the book. Or  the impression of a mosquito that is killed in between our palms.

[image: The Impression of an insert on a page]

Comment: Give it 10,000 years and you've got a fossil.

Comment: It took guts to ask this question!

Comment: Flick the insect itself away and what remains is a *smudge*.

Comment: I call it "fly squash".

Comment: I see it as a "swatted specimen."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this a **pressing**.  Pressing flowers between the pages of books has been a traditional way of creating keepsakes.  [Here's instructions on how to press flowers in books.](https://www.bhg.com/gardening/design/projects/make-pressed-flowers/)

You've just got a more morbid habit of creating pressed insects.

Comment: But then it will include the dry insect too .. here I am perticular about the impression of the insect and not the dry insect..

Comment: @VishalPoddar that's one way of doing it. Another is in a heavy book.

Comment: @VishalPoddar I've added a link in my edit.

Comment: Pressings are done for entomology, rather than your everyday fly-squashing needs.

Answer (score 3):

A relief. I'm being literal and punny.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Nancy. +1 and I enjoyed the pun.

Comment: *Relief* is understood as a representation (in art) rather the object itself, though.